# Using CMS only to manage content, but not display it

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

I'm developing my personal website and want a "blog section" in the main page. I want to use a CMS only to manage the content, but not displaying it in the page with a pre-built template.

What I asking here is if there is a CSM that provides the interface for managing the content, adding, updating, deleting and the main part, an easy way to retrieve these informations with database.

I already did this one time with Wordpress, but maybe there is something more appropriate.

I don't know if I'm clear, so, I want to manage the content with CMS, but display in my own ways.

Comment: Might get better responses at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Cassy Maybe. Is not only a personal website, but a way for me to learn new things like design and frameworks, so I want to avoid a CMS to do all the work.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used it, but ages ago I came across [Symphony CMS](http://symphony-cms.com/) (not to be confused with Symfony, the PHP framework). Symphony uses XML throughout, so once you've edited your content, it can be consumed+cached by pretty much anything.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard of Mut8. The application manages your content and you build your template by using their special css classes for editing. It's pretty good.

http://mut8.me

Answer (score -1):

You could use Joomla and build your own template.
Installing Joomla would take less than 5 minutes. Give it a try !

Joomla Template Tutorial: [Joomla Template Tutorial from NetTuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/creating-your-first-joomla-template/)

In case you want to use another programming language, you could try Python and the Django CMS.
It lets you build a "customized" back-end in a few minutes.

Comment: I wouldn't wish Joomla! on my worst enemy.

Comment: Try to use Croogo. It's based on CakePHP. It's meant to build back-end applications.